# Using wikipedia api contentmodel returns unkown mustache braces

Tags: javascript, json, web-scraping, mediawiki, wikipedia-api

I'm trying to get player match histories from a wiki website using the api. But when I make a request it returns mustach braces instead of the match history.

The url is http://lol.esportspedia.com/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&titles=Acorn/Match%20History&prop=revisions&rvprop=content

example:

```
{
query: {
pages: {
42323: {
pageid: 42323,
ns: 0,
title: "Acorn/Match History",
revisions: [
{
contentformat: "text/x-wiki",
contentmodel: "wikitext",
*: "{{PlayerTabsHeader}} {{MatchHistory|[[SP Name::Acorn]]}}"
}
]
}
}
}
}
```

On the wikipage it shows a table with the wins and losses. How can I get this information?

Comment: "mustache braces" i'm dying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API returns the wikicode of the page in [json format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON), just as you requested. If you would like the rendered version of the code, i.e. the text a user would see, you can just add `action=render` to the article URL, like this:

```
http://lol.esportspedia.com/wiki/Acorn/Match%20History?action=render
```

Comment: I'd've hoped the site where OP got their info on the API would have mentioned this, but I guess not. To be fair, there are too many cut-and-paste guides out there with no info to tell learners what they're really doing.